# Enable a button after another button is clicked and form is submitted

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two buttons: Query and Export. The Export button is disabled by default but when the Query button is clicked and the form has loaded I'd like the export button to be enabled.

Right now  when I click on Query the export is enabled for a second and then goes back to being disabled. I'm assuming this has something to do when the form is submitted and it reverts the Export button to it's original state.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="query">Query</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="export-button" disabled="disabled">Export</button>
```

Here's what my jQuery currently looks like.

```
$(".form").on("submit", function () {
    $('#export-button').prop('disabled', false);
})
```

Comment: _"I'm assuming this has something to do when the form is submitted and it reverts the Export button to it's original state."_ Correct. Unless you're intercepting the submit event, the page will load a new page (or the same page) and the changes will be lost.

Comment: @j08691 is there a way then to somehow store the changes so that after the page is reloaded it will have the button enabled?

Comment: You'd need to store the fact it was clicked somewhere, like in a cookie, session, URL, localStorage, database, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use ajax and enable button on succes?

Comment: @NenadVracar unfortunately I'm not all too familiar with ajax but i'll take a look into it.

Comment: add `return false;` after disable

Comment: @FBHY The export button is enabled but my Query button does not query

Answer (score 0):

I know I posted this awhile back, but in case any one has a similar issues here's what I did to solve it:

First I created a hidden input inside my form to remember whether the button has been clicked or not

```
<input type="hidden" name="clicked" value="true" />
```

In this function, it will either check in session storage if the button has been clicked or it will save it to session storage.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = sessionStorage.getItem('clicked');
        if (clicked == 'true') {
            $('#exportButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#exportButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
    $('#query').on("click", function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', 'true');
    });
    $('#reset').on("click", function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('clicked', 'false');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> jQuery 1.6+ https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/
>   jQuery 1.5- https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

If you have **jQuery 1.6+**, try

```
$('#export-button').removeProp('disabled');
```

If you have **jQuery 1.5** or below try to use:

```
$('#export-button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

And make sure that your form has class `.form`

Comment: The OP's jQuery works fine. It's just that the page is reloading and the button goes back to being disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! anyways I tried that and I still get the same results -export button enables for a second then disables again.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it this way. Assuming you are using a form tag with default get method.

```
  <form>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="query">Query</button>
    <?php 
     if(empty($_GET)) 
        $str = 'disabled="disabled"';
     else 
        $str ="";
    ?>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="export-button" <?php echo $str; ?>>Export</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use php for this. I need to keep it consistent with the rest of code.